# js regex not working. Exact match and or operation

Tags: javascript, regex

The first 3 characters needs to be:

- Exactly either ABC or ACD or BCD
- Then followed be a hyphen -
- Then followed by either a 5 or 8
- Then any 4 numbers

Examples:

```
ABC-56789 (True)
AAA-56789 (False)
```

I have tried this:

```
/^[^ABC$|^ACD$|^BCD$][*-][5|8][0-9]{4}$/
```

Comment: Please may you provide example positive and negative values for the current regex?

Comment: The regex has extra `^` and `$`, also you're using `[]` when you likely meant `()`. Something like `/^(ABC|ACD|BCD)-(5|8)[0-9]{4}$/` may work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use this expression?

```
^(ABC|ACD|BCD)-[5|8]\d{4}$
```

[] means character set. So, [ABC] means any A or B or C, not ABC.
And ^ means negated in []. So, regex you used may not work fine.
If you want to group the tokens, you should use ().
You can also use \d (digit) instead of [0-9].

Comment: Rather than capture group 1, `(ABC|ACD|BCD)`, consider using a non-capture group, `(?:ABC|ACD|BCD)`. Both work, of course, but when readers see a capture group they may assume that you will later extract the contents of that group (which you are not doing), reasoning that you would have used a non-capture group if you would not be doing so. Hardly a biggie, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the regex to the following:

```
/^(ABC|ACD|BCD)-(5|8)[0-9]{4}$/
```

`[]` match single characters, but you want to match three characters in the beginning, so you have to use the `()` to create a capturing group.

Comment: This incorrectly matches `ABC*56789` and `ABC-|6789`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked changing `[5|8]` to `(5|8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```js
const regex = /^(?:ABC|ACD|BCD)-[58][0-9]{4}$/;
[
  'ABC-56789',
  'AAA-56789'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, '==>', regex.test(str));
})
```

Output:

```
ABC-56789 ==> true
AAA-56789 ==> false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at beginning of string
- `(?:ABC|ACD|BCD)` -- non-capture group with OR combinations
- `-` -- literla dash
- `[58]` -- a `5` or `8`
- `[0-9]{4}` -- four digits
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses, not square brackets, to group alternation patterns:

```
^(ABC|ACD|BCD)-[58][0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a single alternation:

```
^(?:ABC|[AB]CD)-[58][0-9]{4}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `ABC` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `[AB]CD` Match either `ACD` or `BCD`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `-` Match literally
- `[58]` Match either `5` or 8`
- `[0-9]{4}` Match 4 digits 0-9
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sm7mCE/1)